# Replace pandas dataframe substrings using regex based on condition at row level

Tags: regex, pandas, dataframe

I need to find a way of replacing a substring in a pandas dataframe at row level based on condition. (`df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Meat 1.7 Kg','Chicken 1.9 Kg','Ground Beef 1.0 Kg','Turkey 1.2 kg','Wagyu 400 g'],'Weight':[10,8,2,6,4],'Mult':[4.0,5.2,5.6,5.9,4.9]})`)

```
    Name               Weight Mult
0   Meat 1.7 Kg        10     4.0
1   Chicken 1.9 Kg      8     5.2
2   Ground Beef 1.0 Kg  2     5.6
3   Turkey 1.2 kg       6     5.9
4   Wagyu 400 g         4     4.9
```

I need to replace the `'Name'` column number with the `'Mult'` column number. The problem is that I need to directly do so when it has 'Kg' or 'kg' at the end, but when it has a 'g' at the end I need to multiply by 1000 and then replace it.

Desired output:

```
    Name               Weight Mult
0   Meat 4.0 Kg        10     4.0
1   Chicken 5.2 Kg      8     5.2
2   Ground Beef 5.6 Kg  2     5.6
3   Turkey 5.9 kg       6     5.9
4   Wagyu 4900 g        4     4.9
```

Maybe it's better to just transform the `'Mult'` value prior replacement and then use the same condition to all rows.

Currently I'm trying this: `[re.sub(r'(\d+\.\d+)\s+[Kk]g$|(\d+\s+)g$', b, a) for a, b in zip(df['refid'], df['Mult'].astype(str))]`, but I don't know how to introduce the condition.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['id'] = df.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'(?i)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(\s*(k)?g)$', lambda z: (str(x['Mult']) if z.group(3) else str(int(x['Mult']*1000))) + z.group(2), x['id']), axis=1)
```

Output of `df`:

```
                     id  Weight  Mult
0           Meat 4.0 Kg      10   4.0
1        Chicken 5.2 Kg       8   5.2
2  Grounded Beef 5.6 Kg       2   5.6
3         Turkey 5.9 kg       6   5.9
4          Wagyu 4900 g       4   4.9
```

*Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive matching on
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1: one or more digits and then an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits
- `(\s*(k)?g)` - Group 2: zero or more whitespaces, an optional Group 3 capturing a `k` and then a `g`
- `$` - end of string.

The `lambda z: (str(x['Mult']) if z.group(3) else str(int(x['Mult']*1000))) + z.group(2)` replacements means the match is replaced with the value from the *Mult* column as is if Group 3 matched + the Group 2 value, or, if Group 3 did not match, the number is multiplied by 1000, turned to integer, converted to a string and returned with Group 2 value right after.